# How do I formulate this XPath expression for selecting a sibling?

Tags: xpath

How do I formulate an XPath expression for obtaining the attribute value for the first input node following the `a` node (`value A`) for the following HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.link.com">link</a>
<input value="value A" />
<input value="value B" />
```

I tried:

```
//input[(preceding-sibling::a[1])]/@value
```

But this gets the value attribute for both input nodes when I only want the attribute for the node for which the `a` node is the nearest preceding sibling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `[1]` predicate on the wrong node. You want the first input that has a `preciding-sibling::a`, not all inputs that follow the first `a` element at a given level.

This should yield the right result:
`//a/following-sibling::input[1]/@value`

It means: for every element `a` found at any level in the document, select the first `input` element that follows it, while being its sibling. Then read its `value` attribute.

For this input:

```
<xml>
  <p>
    <input value="value A" />
    <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a>
    <input value="value B" />
    <input value="value C" />
  </p>
  <p> 
    <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a>
    <input value="value D" />
    <input value="value E" />
    <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a>
    <input value="value F" />
  </p>
</xml>
```

It returns:

- value B
- value D
- value F

### EDIT

This works provided that there are no elements between `a` and the first `input` that follows it.

For instance, with input like this:

```
    <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a>
    <strong>OMG NOEZ!</strong>
    <input value="value A" />
```

value A still gets selected

If it's OK, keep the above expression. If it's not, modify it like this to filter other elements:

`//a/following-sibling::*[1][self::input]/@value`

This selects the first following sibling of `a`, no matter what the tag is and only after it's selected does it check the actual tag. This way the `input` that's further at the same level is not chosen.